# What is the format of a cookie expiration date represented in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, json, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I have exported a cookie to a JSON file ,However the expirationDate appears as follow:-

```
"expirationDate": 1685302374.80881,
```

Now I want to know the format of that date ,where is the month ,the day ,and the year of expiration.

Because I want to edit it and import it again to the browser so it lasts longer.

Comment: Looks like seconds since 1970-01-01. Try `console.log(new Date(1685302374.80881 * 1000))`

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Wow ,Yes it seems like that ,How did you figure it out ?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros And ,why does multiplying by 1000 works ?

Comment: How did I figure it out? Well, it looks like Unix time. Why do you have to multiply by a thousand? Because the `Date` constructor takes milliseconds as a value, not seconds.